# Getting name of control (listbox) by selected item (listboxitem) - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have many listbox in my project. I moving selected item from one listbox to another.
In XAML file i biniding SelectedItem to my property.

```xaml
<GroupBox Header="A"  Grid.Column="0">
  <ListBox Width="200" Name="lbWMSmaterials" ItemsSource="{Binding WMSmaterialItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
</GroupBox>
<GroupBox Header="B"  Grid.Column="1">
  <ListBox Width="200" Name="lbCommonMaterials" ItemsSource="{Binding commonMaterialItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</GroupBox>
<Button Command="{Binding MoveListBoxItem}" CommandParameter="common_material_down" Grid.Column="5" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyleDown}" Name="d_c_m" />
<Button Command="{Binding MoveListBoxItem}" CommandParameter="common_material_up" Grid.Column="6" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyleUpAll}" Name="u_c_m" />
```

I'm binding command in my buttons to perform some logic, also i pass command parameter to know with button i clicked. Each button moving selected item to another listbox.

```cs
public DemoItem SelectedItem { get; set; }

public DelegateCommand<string> MoveListBoxItem
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand<string>(
                  new Action<string>(
                    (e) =>
                    {
                        switch (e)
                        {
                            case "common_material_down":
                                if (SelectedItemDown != null)
                                {
                                    WMSarticleItems.Add(SelectedItemDown);
                                    this.Remove(SelectedItemDown);
                                }
                                break;

                             //... other cases
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }),
                  (e) => { return true; });
            }
```

I need to know **name** of listbox currently related with me SelectedItem property.

How to do it without breaking MVVM pattern?
(Workaround is create many SelectedItem property for each lisbox, but i want to have only one)

Comment: it is much better to have different properties for each `SelecteItem` as otherwise you must have a lot of conditions to filter what should be done with which. No to mention lack of transparence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're *not* using MVVM. In MVVM, we don't move *UI objects*, instead we manipulate *data objects*. So, if you *were* using MVVM, then you wouldn't need to know the name of any UI element.

Instead of that, you'd simply bind a `SelectedItem` property in your view model to the `SelectedItem` property of your `ListBox` *and add this data object (or a copy of it) into the collection the is data bound to the relevant `ListBox` that you want to move the item to. In this case, your `ICommand` code would be something like this:

```
Collection1.Remove(Collection1.Where(c => c.Equals(SelectedItem)).Single());
Collection2.Add(SelectedItem);
```

And your XAML would be something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}".../>
...
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection2}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem2}"../>
```